# Using certificate-constrained access tokens created by private key used to authentication (with private_key_jwt)

Tags: tls, oauth2, openid-connect, mutual

I have a OIDC provider that can't use mutual TLS authentication due to mTLS problems like certificates expiration (what if client didn't rotate certificate and it's expired now? Client cant authenticate to server to e.g. inform server that client has new certificate, so client loss whole access and seems to be useless), or what if OCSP is unavailable, prompting user about certificate if we don't have another port for mTLS etc.

But mTLS give us a big security improvment: certificate-constrained access tokens.

In comparison to DPoP it has big advantage: there are no DPoP token and replay attack is impossible.

So I thought about a bit modified DPoP. We can create self-signed x509 certificate (signed by the same private key that we are using to authenticate using private_key_jwt method) every request to resource server and then use DPoP with earlier generated certificate. (In my case resource servers can support mTLS, while they are only API).

What it provides? It provides that DPoP token can't be reused because we must estabilish mTLS connection to use it. If attacker doesn't know private key, then can't do anything even if DPoP token has leaked.

Do you see any problems in my solution? Asking because I'm not security expert and I might have missed something.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are proposing to use a self-signed X.509 certificate as a form of proof-of-possession (PoP) token to secure access to resource servers. Using a self-signed certificate in this way could provide some security benefits, such as being able to verify that the certificate was issued by the client's private key and preventing replay attacks, as you mentioned.

However, there are a few potential issues with this approach that you should consider:

**1. Trust:** In order for the resource server to trust the self-signed certificate and grant access to the client, it must be configured to trust the client's private key. This requires manually installing the client's public key or certificate on the resource server, which may not be practical or desirable in some cases.

**2. Revocation:** There is no built-in mechanism for revoking a self-signed certificate. If the client's private key is compromised or the certificate is no longer needed, it cannot be easily revoked. This could potentially allow an attacker to gain unauthorized access to the resource server even after the client's access has been terminated.

**3. Man-in-the-middle attacks:** Because the self-signed certificate is not signed by a trusted certificate authority (CA), it is not protected against man-in-the-middle attacks. An attacker could potentially intercept the self-signed certificate and use it to gain unauthorized access to the resource server.

**4. Certificate expiration:** You mentioned that one of the issues with mutual TLS authentication is that client certificates can expire, causing authentication to fail. Using self-signed certificates as PoP tokens could also suffer from this issue if they are set to expire.

Overall, while using self-signed certificates as PoP tokens may provide some security benefits, it is important to carefully consider the potential drawbacks and whether they are acceptable for your use case. It may be worth considering alternative approaches, such as using a trusted third-party CA to sign the client's certificates or using a different form of PoP token, such as a JSON Web Token (JWT) or a one-time-use token.

Comment: Yes, I want to use X.509 certificates as form of PoP, but only as additional layer that prevents replay attacks. So: 1. Client public key will be available in access token signed by some authorization server, so we dont need to install client certificates on resource server. 2. These certificates will be created every request with short lifetime (about 10 seconds), so revocation is not necessary. 3. But if attacker could intercept certificate, then still can't do mTLS handshake because attacker hasn't private key. 1/2

Comment: 4. It's not problem, because these certificates are intended to has short lifetime. Now, do you see any security risks?